# backup android sms to gmail?

Tags: android, email, gmail-imap

I'm trying to learn from google code and I got stuck in some problems.

1. what is imapstore.jar? **how to get it?**
2. all "import com.android.email.mail.*" is cannot resolved, **how to fix it?**

I already search it but still cannot find the answer, I hope I cane get some helps here.
can someone help me? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imapstore.jar is an external library that I presume you want to use. The import statement should resolve itself when you add that library to your build path. You can obtain the library from http://android-sms.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/android-client/external/imapstore.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This package is implemented over the "imap.protocol" package, which implements the protocol-level commands.

A connected IMAPStore maintains a pool of IMAP protocol objects for
use in communicating with the IMAP server.The IMAPStore will create
the initial AUTHENTICATED connection and seed the pool with this
connection. As folders are opened and new IMAP protocol objects are
needed, the IMAPStore will provide them from the connection pool,
or create them if none are available. When a folder is closed,
its IMAP protocol object is returned to the connection pool if the
pool is not over capacity. The pool size can be configured by setting
the mail.imap.connectionpoolsize property.

For more to know visit this link:

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4-sources.jar!/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore.java?format=ok